# How to dynamically create Angular module provider list from * import

Tags: angular, typescript, import

I'm attempting (mostly out of curiosity at this point) to streamline importing my services into my module file and I'm not entirely sure if its possible.  It SEEMS possible, but I'm hitting a wall.  The end goal is to be able to create a barrel file for my services in another folder and have everything in that file get imported into the module that references that barrel file.  Here is an example of what I'd like to do:

```
import * as SERVICES from './services';
@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [
    ...Object.values(SERVICES)
  ]
})
export class ProjectsModule { }
```

Its especially frustrating because logging "Object.values(SERVICES)" shows that its creating an array of service objects, yet the angular CLI continues to throw "only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [?null?]".

I have tried manually iterating across the SERVICES object, rather than using Object.values.  I've tried using a map function to create a provider object out of each value that is returned from Object.values(SERVICES).

Even more frustrating is that the following actually works fine:

```
providers: [
    SERVICES.Service1,
    SERVICES.Service2,
    SERVICES.Service3
  ]
```

But that defeats the point of being able to update a barrel file without adjusting the module imports.

For some reason converting these properties to an array breaks something.  I'm assuming I'm missing some key information about how typescript actually imports things. I would expect that what I'm attempting to do would behave like this, only dynamically:

```
import { service1, service2, service3 } from './services';

const myServices = [
        service1, 
        service2, 
        service3 
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [
    ...myServices
  ]
})
export class ProjectsModule { }
```

Edit: As per requested, here is my auto generated barrel file

```
export * from './project.resolver';
export * from './projects.resolver';
export * from './projects.service';
```

All services are Injectable and are not using the new "providedIn: 'root'" syntax.

Comment: Can you provide the code from ./services.ts ?

Comment: No problem, I just updated it.

Comment: does angular evaluate `Object.values(SERVICES)` at compile time? if not, it is not possible :)

Comment: @ABOS Ohh man, you may be right.  I didn't even think about that.

Comment: @Brandon, perhaps decorator can help?

Comment: @ABOS could you explain a little more what you mean? I haven't worked much with decorators yet.

Comment: I am trying, will reply back once done

Comment: please check this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yzvogx, have done it in a rush, so not sure if I am missing something. btw, check console and see output from dynamically injected services.

Comment: I appreciate it!  I'll try and play around with that example and see if I can make it work for my application.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

in your services.ts file:

```
export const SERVICES = [
    Service1,
    Service2,
    Service3,
];
```

then import in your ProjectsModule

```
import { SERVICES } from './services';

@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [
    ...SERVICES
  ]
})
export class ProjectsModule { }
```